# get some random data from specified data in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

Lets suppose I  have some data, `data=[ 3 4 5 6 55 66 733 223 55 666 333 24]` I want get random data form this data , lets suppose something like

```
 myrand= randomdata(data, 4)
```

it should return 4 data from our sample vector,
**How can I do it in matlab 2011?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`randperm(n,k)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to choose `k` unique numbers from a list  of `[1:n]`. So, to solve our case, feed `n` as `numel(data)` and `k` as `4`, like so -

```
randperm(numel(data),4)
```

---

As it turns out, it seems `MATLAB 2011` doesn't support the second argument to  choose the number of elements. So, one workaround is to get randomized indices for all possible indices in `data` and select the first `4` indices, which could be used to index into `data` for the desired output, like so -

```
rand_idx = randperm(numel(data))
out = data(rand_idx(1:4))
```

This selection might not follow the *uniform-distribution* for randomness, as we are always making the selection with the first `4` numbers. Instead, you can distribute the selection to be more *uniform* by using linearly spaced indices, like so -

```
data(rand_idx(round(linspace(1,numel(data),4))))
```

Sample run -

```
>> data = [ 3 4 5 6 55 66 733 223 55 666 333 24];
>> rand_idx = randperm(numel(data));
>> data(rand_idx(1:4))
ans =
    55     4    24     6
>> data(rand_idx(round(linspace(1,numel(data),4))))
ans =
    55    66   733     3
```

Comment: @zhilevan You tried just copy n pasted version, right?

Comment: test, yes I just try to copy paste this, but also try `data = [ 3 4 5 6 55 66 733 223 55 666 333 24]; randperm(numel(data),4)` and see `??? Error using ==> randperm
Too many input arguments.
 ` and then take a look and `randperm` but dont see anything about that first arguments can be a vector

Comment: @zhilevan What's your MATLAB version? Also, can you try and see if this throws any error - `randperm(numel(data))`?

Comment: I told on question I am using matlab 2011

Comment: @zhilevan Does `randperm(numel(data))` throw any error? Once it works, we can make the solution work with it.

Comment: No , but It return  permutation of my data, not n number of them

Comment: @zhilevan Check out the edits please. As it turns out, it was a version issue.